# How to make sure to create the correct key:value pair in dictionary for Python with for loops and try except?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, try-except

I am trying to do the bolded line below when adding the elements back to the dictionary, but I want to make sure it is doing what I want it to do. I put the csv texts at the bottom as well. I want to make sure that if the same income type appear multiple times, my function would be able to capture it and my function ignores income with missing or invalid amounts with the try and except below.

## iterate over each line in the list

```
for line in lines:

    # strip white spaces in the line
    line = line.strip()

    # split items in the line by :
    income_list = line.split(':')

    # if empty amount, skip the line
    if len(income_list) <= 1:
        continue

    # set the type and amount as a variable and strip white space
    income_type = income_list[0].strip()
    total_income_amount = income_list[1].strip()

    # try and except to catch invalid amount
    try:
        total_income_amount = float(total_income_amount)
        
        **#add income type and amount to income dictionary** 
        income[income_type] = income.get(income_type, 0) + total_income_amount
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

**If this is the income list in csv: But we want to be able to sort it according to the expense type entered.**

stock: 10000
estate: 2000
work: 80000
investment: 30000
stock: 20000
investment:1000
donation:
contract: sss

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
records = []  # for storing line data

for line in lines:

    # Need to split correctly first.
    income_list = line.strip().replace(": ", ":").split(" ") # ['stock:10000', 'estate:2000', ...]

    # loop over each income data of the line
    income = {}
    for i in income_list:

        # get type and amount
        income_type, income_amount = [tmp.strip() for tmp in i.strip().split(":")]

        # try if the value is valid
        try:
            if income_type not in income.keys():
                income[income_type] = float(income_amount)
            else:
                income[income_type] += float(income_amount)
        except:
            continue
    
    # save this line data to the records
    records.append(income)

# do your sorting here as needed with 'records'
# keep in mind not all data have the same keys
# so you need to deal with null key values

# for example assuming all data has the key "stock"
sorted_by_stock_asc = sorted(records, key=lambda x: x["stock"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one more question regarding my codes, could you please help me?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248857/how-to-export-selected-dictionary-data-into-a-file-in-python